# Coset of null space by an element

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $Ax$ = $b$ where $b$ is non-zero is a system of linear equations. Here $A$ is any matrix and $b$ is a vector.

I have been trying to prove that if $Ax$ = $b$ is consistent then

$T$$^{-1}$($b$) = $N$($T$)+$x$ where $N$($T$) is the null space of the corresponding linear transformation $T$.

This has been my attempt.

Let $w$ $\in$ $N$($T$)+$x$

Then $w$ = $a$+$x$ for some $a$ $\in$ $N$($T$)

Then $T$($w$) = $T$($a$)+$T$($x$) = $b$

Hence $N$($T$)+$x$ $\subseteq$ $T$$^{-1}$($b$)

Now how to show the other side?

If I let $y$ $\in$ $T$$^{-1}$($b$)

Then how can I write $y$ = $a$ + $x$ for some $a$ $\in$ $N$($T$) ?

Comment: I think you should specify what you mean for the symbols you are using. What are $A$, $b$, $T$ and so on? I guess $b$ is a vector in some vector space $V$ and $A$ is a linear map, maybe from $V$ to itself. What is $T$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So $T:V \rightarrow W$ is $T(x)=Ax$. Suppose $x_0 \in V$ is such that $T(x_0)=Ax_0=b$ for some given $b \in W$. You want to prove that the set
$$T^{-1}(\{b\})=x_0+N(T).$$
Let $y \in T^{-1}(\{b\})$, then  $T(y)=b$. But we also know that $T(x_0)=b$. This means $T(x_0-y)=T(x_0)-T(y)=b-b=0$. So $y-x_0 \in N(T)$. Consequently,
$$y \in x_0+N(T) \implies T^{-1}(\{b\}) \subseteq x_0+N(T).$$